# IIS Express or Cassini

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-express, cassini

I'm a little confused about something.  I am using Visual Studio 2010 and am a little unsure whether VS 2010 uses IIS Express or Cassini when running web applications.  What is the difference?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**VS 2010 SP1** supports both IIS Express and Cassini (VS 2010 supports only cassini). You can configure your project to use IIS Express or Cassini.

By default VS 2010 SP1 uses Cassini and to change right click on your web site/web application and select "use iis express". (When IIS Express used you would find a IIS Express tray icon and there you can see all the running sites)

[image: IIS Express Tray ICON]

Answer (score 5):

I think [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx) topic will answers most of your questions. In short:

- wheter you use Cassini or IIS Express depends on your project's configuration
- IIS Express has a richer feature pack.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend IIS Express, since I have spent 2+ days chasing bugs that worked fine in Cassini that now rear their ugly heads in IIS Express (and trying to publish to IIS7.5).  (These are mainly configuration bugs for SimpleMembershipProvider)