# Invoke ASMX Web Service without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, frameworks

There are two PCs: In PC1, I have created ASMX Web Service and Hosted in local IIS.

My URL is like

```
XXX.XXX.X.103:82/WebService.asmx
```

Now, there is no Visual Studio in PC2, I just installed Framework 4.5.

How do I invoke and test that `ASMX Web Service` using only Framework?

Because when I run that URL in browser, I got the list of Services but not able to test it. How to solve with using only ".NET Framework"?

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

I am not getting this "Test Method" in PC2 and "Invoke Button".

Comment: [6 Different ways to test web service](http://wso2.com/library/3862/)

Comment: @RahulNikate but how to test using browser and without "Visual Studio". I didn't find any solution. Thanks!!

Comment: you can open service in browser like this. http://XXX.XXX.X.103:82/WebService.asmx/FunctionNameHere

Comment: @RahulNikate but how to test or invoke it? I am not getting "invoke" button.

Comment: How do you open web site in browser. Same way open service url in browser. If possible add screen shot to see what you are getting

Comment: @RahulNikate I am getting the web service operations using URL, but  cannot able to test it.

Comment: Could you please add screen shot in your question

Comment: @RahulNikate see my edit, I attached screen shot. Thanks!!

Comment: Are you getting any error on while opening service in browser in PC2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer:

Here is the code that I added in "**Web.Config**".

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
      <add name="HttpGet"/>
      <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
 </webServices>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have any `nullable` arguments on the input of the web service method you are trying to test, the `Invoke` button will not show up.

Answer (score -2):

`ASMX` services are designed to run in IIS.  When using Visual Studio, a light weight IIS ([`Cassini`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11454624/iis-express-or-cassini)) is used.

You will need to install IIS onto PC2.

Comment: Richard, I installed IIS, but how to test now that Web Service? I am not getting that "Invoke" button. Thanks brother.

Comment: You need to create the "Application/Virtual Directory" in IIS and then point it to the folder container the ASMX service.

Comment: I tried it but do not able to get "Invoke Button" on PC2. @Richard